# How to send and listen message via telnet

Tags: tcp, telnet

I have a custom TCP server on localhost and I want to test it via window telnet. When a message sent to my TCP server with specified format (e.g `GO|CD1502|` with special characters) then my server send back to client a response message (e.g `OK` or `ERROR`).

Now, I want to test my server via telnet client on window 11. These are steps I've done to sent message

- Open telnet
- Open connection: `open 127.0.0.1 6565` (my tcp server listening ip and port)
- Using escape character (`Ctrl + ]`) to back command terminal
- Send message: `send GO|CD1502|`
- Checking server, message received and sent response message

-> How do I check response message from telnet terminal when stream listening message was escaped?